# ReactJS app not working in Safari browser

Tags: reactjs, safari

I am trying to run my Reactjs published app in Safari browser and I get the below error. I have no idea how the **start.js** file is created and what that line of code is going to do. Please advise.

```
    (anonymous function) (start.js:1:1108)
    Global Code (start.js:1:1108)
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...'. Expected a property name.
    promiseReactionJob
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error likely came from an extension, you can disable all extensions and try again.

Comment: Browser extension? I am using BrowserStack to test.